# Android native library is slower than excutables

Tags: android, android-ndk

Running an executable from adb shell can reach 100 MIPS, while using Android native library can only reach 30 MIPS on the same device. Is this normal with the Android ndk/jni/... overhead taken into consideration?

The executable and the native binary are compiled with the same flags, but maybe different compilers.

- The executable is compiled with `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`,the output of `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version`:

  > arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2014.05-29) 4.8.3 20140320 (prerelease)
  >   Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  >   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  >   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
- The native library is compiled by adding the following commands in *build.gradle* of the Android Studio project.

  ```
    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
          // for neon optimization:
          abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
          cppFlags "-DHAVE_NEON -O3 -Wno-parentheses -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a"
      }
  }
  ```

## I find out the difference comes from that the native library is running in debug mode, when I change to release mode, the native library and executable have comparable MIPS.

Comment: No, this is not expected. Where do the frames come from? This could be the bottleneck, not C++. You can check CPU utilization to differentiate between underoptimized code and slow frame arrival.

Comment: Frames?  Sorry, I am talking about millions of instructions per second, what's the relationship with frames?

Comment: Sorry, I looked on a small phone screen, and MIPS transformed to FPS to me

Comment: How do you measure MIPS? Could the difference be that the executable uses 4 threads in parallel (on a multi-core device), while the library is compiled single-threaded?

Comment: I measure MIPS by computing a matrix vector multiplication. The difference is that I use different compilers for the executable and native library.

Comment: If you have C files, `cppFlags` will not be applied to them, and optimization may be missing. To be on the safe side, use `cFlags` instead.

Comment: The executable and the native library use the same piece of code for matrix vector multiplication. But the native library code are all written in cpp files and should be compiled by g++ compiler(I don't know which compiler Android Studio select) while the executable source code are written in c files and compiled by the gcc compiler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130946/discussion-between-robert-li-and-alex-cohn).